# Can't remove index.php from codeigniter URL in AWS (ec2-user)

Tags: amazon-web-services, codeigniter, amazon-ec2, codeigniter-3

I'm building an application using `AWS`. Shown below is the `.htaccess` I'm using,

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
  </IfModule>
```

When using this `.htaccess` I'm getting the following error,

[image]

If the `.htaccess` is not used, everything works fine. Any guidance on how to solve this is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The error is probably not due to .htaccess. Most likely you have not set up the server configuration properly and given permission for the folder to be accessed.

In an Apache web server, that permission is often set in the `<Directory>` section of a  config. Here's a generic example.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example/htdocs

  <Directory /var/www/example/htdocs>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] 
  </Directory>

  # many other directives too

</VirtualHost>
```

The directive that provides permission is the line `Require all granted`. The above is typically found in a file stored in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`.

Notice that you can use the RewriteEngine in server configuration files. In fact, that is the best way. Using `.htaccess` should only be done when you cannot edit configuration files yourself, i.e. shared hosting. But since you are on AWS you can and must manage the configuration yourself. Some reading that provides a good explanation of why [you should not use .htaccess](https://www.danielmorell.com/guides/htaccess-seo/basics/dont-use-htaccess-unless-you-must).

The "it works without .htaccess" behavior is probably because the directive `AllowOverride None` is in effect. This directive turns off the ability to use `.htaccess` on a directory. When you try "override directives" via `.htaccess` then permission is denied.

Another possible problem is that the folder holding `index.php` does not have the correct "ownership" which is typically "www-data:www-data" through variations are found.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the below file:

/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf

You will see the below codes:

```
 <Directory /var/www/html/foldername>
     AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
```

Replace the above code with this:

```
  <Directory /var/www/vhosts/foldername>
      Options -FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
 </Directory>
```

Note: Watch out code indentation, wrong indentation will leads error.